# No Buildpack found while deploying to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

[image: FileTree]

This is my file tree containing a folder for my Vue app (client folder) and my NodeJS server (server folder).

When I try uploading to Heroku, I get an error saying that `no matching buildpacks could be found`, and that's I believe due to my `source folder` not having a `package.js` and that being because I have one in the `client` and `server` folders.

So how can I accomplish deploying both my client and server-side in one Heroku app, or would I need to split my whole app in one Heroku Front-End App and one Heroku Back-End App?

I'm sorry for such a stupid question, but I am really confused on how to put my app live, since it's finally finished after a month of work.

Answer (score 1):

> No Buildpack found while deploying to Heroku .. When I try uploading to Heroku, I get an error saying that no matching buildpacks could be found, and that's I believe due to my source folder not having a package.js

Correct, this error "no buildpack found" happens because Heroku looks at (only) your root directory and cannot determine what language/framework you are using.

> The package.json file defines the dependencies that should be installed with your application. To create a package.json file for your app, run the command npm init in the root directory of your app.
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#declare-app-dependencies

I'd recommend reading the [heroku node docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs) and deploying a "hello world" application first, as a learning experience. You'll also want to read about [the Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile).

Deploying a client-server application to Heroku is quite common, all [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) apps work this way (a single deploy). But, for node apps, there are many different ways to deploy, and there is no official (documented) way to organize your code, AFAIK.

Comment: I read through the docs before when I was once deploying just a node server to Heroku, and I made it work without any issues. My current problem with this server-client app is that after fixing the buildpacks issue, when I visit the Heroku app link it goes to the server; showing `Cannot GET /`, when all I want is for it to go to my Vue app when I visit the link. And that's really what I don't understand.